# Detect if user has "read" an article with Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-javascript-sdk

Okay so I read this post "http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10373897/deleting-a-previosly-posted-article-with-opengraph-or-check-if-said-article-has" but I'm using the news.reads action type.

So on the website when a user logs in with Facebook, and grant publishing permissions, every post they read gets pushed to their timeline. Everything is fine until they refresh/revisit the same article where `facebook.php` emits a `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3501) User is already associated to the article object on a unique action type Read. Original Action ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

I am fine that there is a bug with the built in news.reads OG and it being unique, but I was wondering if there was away to detect if a user has already read/viewed it.

---

Something like:

```
if (user is logged in [$user]) {
    if (user hasn't read article) {
        $facebook->api(/me......);
    } else if (user has read the article) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
} else { // If not logged in
    echo "login";
}
```

Hopefully that's possible, otherwise it would be a total bummer that I/user cannot view a page a second time without the facebook.php stopping the rest of the page being processed (its before the `<html>` tag).

**Note:** I prefer the PHP SDK, but am willing to use JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* have stored the info that user *foo* has read article *bar* in your database anyway – since approval requirements for read action demand that you provide the user with an easy way to unpublish this action again.

Comment: You don't happen to have some code, or example that I could understand? All the built-in OG is not clear to me, compared to the custom (cookie tutorial/coffee store tutorial/etc.). Even documentation that would let me know about *foo*